# How to make swipe function work dynamically on a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a cross-platform mobile application using Cordova. I have an HTML page with a table. I have a button `add row` when clicked adds a new row to my table. I need an iOS-like swipe action to have a delete action. I used `touchstart` event to swipe a static row in my table. That works fine but not with dynamically created table rows. How to do this swipe action?

This is the code I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="fortable">
    <table id="cashreg">
        <tr>
            <td class="tablecellbackground"><div class="del" id="d1" ><p>Delete</p></div><div id="cells" class="cells"><div class="denom"><p>Start Time</p></div><div class="cnt"><p>Select Item</p></div><div class="tots"><p>Employee</p></div><div class="tots1"><p>Price</p></div></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="button" class="addmore">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

For adding a row to the table:

```
$(".addmore").click(function(){
    var rows = $("#cashreg tr").length+1;
    $("#cashreg").append('<tr><td class="tablecellbackground"><div class="cells"><div class="denom"><p>Start Time</p></div><div class="cnt"><p>Select Item</p></div><div class="tots"><p>Employee</p></div><div class="tots1"><p>Price</p></div><div class="del"><p>Delete</p></div></div></td></tr>');
});
```

For iOS-like swipe:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('cells')[0];
    ontouch(el, function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){
        var touchreport = ''
        touchreport += '<b>Dir:</b> ' + dir + '<br />'
        touchreport += '<b>Phase:</b> ' + phase + '<br />'
        touchreport += '<b>Swipe Type:</b> ' + swipetype + '<br />'
        touchreport += '<b>Distance:</b> ' + distance + '<br />'
        if(dir=="left"){
            left=parseInt(($(".cells").css("top")).replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ))-distance;
            $(".cells").css("left","-"+left+"px")
        }
        if(dir=="right"){
            if($(".cells").css("left")== "-166px"){
                //left=parseInt(($(".cells").css("top")).replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ))-distance;
                $(".cells").css("left","0px")
            }
        }
        if(dir=="none"){
            // document.getElementById("hi").value=el.pageX;
        }
    })
}, false)

function ontouch(el, callback){
    var touchsurface = el,
    dir,
    swipeType,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 50, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 500, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    handletouch = callback || function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){}

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        dir = 'none'
        swipeType = 'none'
        dist = 0
        startX = touchobj.pageX
        startY = touchobj.pageY
        startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
        handletouch(e, 'none', 'start', swipeType, 0) // fire callback function with params dir="none", phase="start", swipetype="none" etc
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        if (Math.abs(distX) > Math.abs(distY)){ // if distance traveled horizontally is greater than vertically, consider this a horizontal movement
            dir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right'
            handletouch(e, dir, 'move', swipeType, distX) // fire callback function with params dir="left|right", phase="move", swipetype="none" etc
        }
        else{ // else consider this a vertical movement
            dir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down'
            handletouch(e, dir, 'move', swipeType, distY) // fire callback function with params dir="up|down", phase="move", swipetype="none" etc
        }
        e.preventDefault()
        // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
    }, false)

    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipeType = dir // set swipeType to either "left" or "right"
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipeType = dir // set swipeType to either "top" or "down"
            }
        }
        // Fire callback function with params dir="left|right|up|down", phase="end", swipetype=dir etc:
        handletouch(e, dir, 'end', swipeType, (dir =='left' || dir =='right')? distX : distY)
        e.preventDefault()
        if(dir=="left"){
            if(distX>-100){
                $(".cells").css("left","0px")
            }
            else if(distX<-50 && distX>-100){
                $(".cells").css("left","-166px")
            }
            else{
                $(".cells").css("left","-166px")
            }
        }
    }, false)
}
```

How to make this swipe apply to a newly added table row?

Answer (score 2):

You should use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to deal with new elements added dynamically by js :

```
$("body").on('touchstart click','#cashreg tr', function(e){

})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But where to have this function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance) event? Can you please explain how to do it?@Zakaria Acharki

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you bind your cells elements with the event `ontouch` in the `load` function. It means that only the elements present on load will be bound. You need to register the `ontouch` event on your newly created row element as well.

With your example, you could try to use the `ontouch` html attribute directly, i.e.:

```
 <div class="cells" ontouchstart="...">
```

or simply bind the touch event to your body and check for the `cells` class in the handler:

```
 var el = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 ontouch(el, function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){
     if($(evt.target).hasClass("cells")){
         // your code
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you But how to bind them? Can you please help me code?@Shitsu

Comment: my bad. Edited the answer.

Comment: I could not get you. Can you please send  code snippet. or explain me in simple way? @Shitsu

Comment: the second snippet is simply the first lines of your load function, but with some modifications (bound to body and an if). The first works exactly like `onclick="function()"`. What is unclear ?

Comment: I tried with first function. ontouchstart="ontouch(this)", It works dynamically but it works slower. Why?